# Doctrine query, error

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine

I have query:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$query = $em->createQuery(
    'SELECT 
       Bank_ID, 
       Status, 
       COUNT(Bank_ID) 
    FROM 
       OmnisoftIntegBundle:IntClientBank 
    WHERE 
       status = 30 or status = 50 or status = 35 or status = 37 
    GROUP BY Bank_ID, Status;'
);

$result = $query->getResult();

return new JsonResponse(array('data' => $result, 'success' => true))
```

And symfony show error:

> [2/2] QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 84: Error: Expected
>   end of string, got 'status'  + [1/2] QueryException: SELECT Bank_ID,
>   Status, COUNT(Bank_ID) FROM OmnisoftIntegBundle:IntClientBank WHERE
>   status = 30 or status = 50 or status = 35 or status = 37 GROUP BY
>   Bank_ID, Status;

Comment: Do you know that IN predicate could easily do the or -> or -> or -> ... -> or logic for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove ';' at the end of your query.